# Reusing Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a couple of class instance variables: `userSF` which is a `SessionFactory` and `userCfg` which is a `Configuration` set up to use `user.cfg.xml`. When I have someone log into my application their database login information is grabbed from a file the following happens:

```
userCfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
userCfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
userSF = userCfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

When the user logs out of the application it closes the session factory. then when another user tries to log in that same code is called with username and password changing based on who is logging in. The problem is that the second time it's called I'm getting an exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: HHH000469: The ClassLoaderService can not be reused. This instance was stopped already.
```

Is there a way to reuse the SessionFactory variable for multiple logins?

Answer (score 2):

You should not create a `SessionFactory` for each logged in user / configuration. It is a very costly component and should target the `Singleton` pattern. Use a single instance per context within your application.

If you have multiple configurations you can cache multiple instances in application scope. Depending on your application this maybe a static `Singleton` class using a `Map<MyUserPasswordKey, SessionFactory>` or in an JAVA-EE container a `@ApplicationScoped` EJB or JSF-Bean.

In case a context based on a `user-password` key will lead to too many `SessionFactory` instances you maybe should change your application to either manage them in permission groups or restrict your functionality within your data access or service layer.

Comment: How would I go about using multiple connections then? The reason I ask is because each user has different permissions in the database.

Comment: I don't know why you have dynamic permissions depending on given user to your database and don't restrict data access in your data access layer but even if this is a requirement you can hold instances for each `user-password` combination.